# How can I find an empty string in this data structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need that when a button is pressed, a state check is made, and depending on the result, one thing or another is done. Basically, check that there is no empty "value" field, and in that case redirect to another page of the application. With code it looks better:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState<ISignUpFormData>({
    username: { value: "", valid: true, unique: true },
    email: { value: "", valid: true, unique: true },
    password: { value: "", valid: true },
    birthdate: { value: "", valid: true },
  });

const handleClick = async (e:any) => {
    let canContinue = true;
    const keys = Object.keys(formData);
    keys.forEach(key => console.log()) // ??? keys is an array of strings, i need to access to "username".value to check if it is "" o not
  }
```

The value fields are filled by controlled inputs

My question is: how do I loop through the keys of an object whose values ​​are another object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` and `find()` ... it will return `undefined` if there is not entry with an empty string

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState<ISignUpFormData>({
   username: { value: "", valid: true, unique: true },
   email: { value: "", valid: true, unique: true },
   password: { value: "", valid: true },
   birthdate: { value: "", valid: true },
})

const handleClick = () => {
   const hasEmptyString = Object.values(formData).find(obj => obj.value === '');
   //Returns object with empty string id there is any
   //returns undefined if there is not entry with empty string
   console.log(hasEmptyString);
}
```

Or as pointed out in the comments by [plichard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) you can use `some()` which will only return `true`/`false` instead of returning the whole object that has an empty value

```
const hasEmptyString = Object.values(formData).some(obj => obj.value === '');
```

Comment: You suld be using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) not `find()` here as it returns a boolean. `const hasEmptyString = Object.values(formData).some(({value}) => value === '')`

Comment: but I believe `find` will stop as soon as it finds an entry that is empty , `some` will iterate through all the items, so this might be better for performance... also if he wants to throw some kind of message `find` will return the object that the message is related to

Comment: No, `some()` stops on first match  (`every()` iterates all)

Comment: you're right... i'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.entries to get key and value and then check if any of the value has empty string.

Some naive implementation below.

Refer to this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
 const object1 = {
    username: { value: "", valid: true, unique: true },
    email: { value: "", valid: true, unique: true },
    password: { value: "", valid: true },
    birthdate: { value: "", valid: true },
  }

let hasEmptyString = false;
for (const [key, formKey] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  if(formKey.value === ""){
    hasEmptyString = true
    break
  }

}
if(!hasEmptyString){
  // redirect to 
}

console.log(hasEmptyString)
```